# How to align text and a plot in a two-column layout in a quarto document rendering to power point presentation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, powerpoint, quarto

The following Quarto document is rendered to a Power Point presentation with a title slide and a Two Content Layout slide. In the Two Content Layout slide the text is aligned at the top of the placeholder, while the figure is vertically aligned at the middle of the placeholder.

````
---
title: "Text+Plot"
format: pptx
---

# Slide with a text and a plot
:::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="30%"}
How to adjust the plot on the right so that its top is aligned with this text's top?
:::
::: {.column width="70%"}
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point()
```
:::
::::::
````

How can we adjust the alignment so that both text and plot are centered vertically or both are top-aligned? If we need to change the Power Point template, which settings to look for there?